# Conversion of dictionary into a file retaining the double quotes

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert a `dictionary` into a `file` which needs to be passed for `curl` command. I need to update some of the values in `dictionary`, when i dump using the `json.dump` its getting written as `string` format as expected. But the double quotes is replaced into single quotes. Is there a way to retain the `dictionary` to a `file` in exact format?
following is my code

**Receiving output**:

```
{
    'type': 'taskSap',
    'actions': {
        'abortActions': [],
        'emailNotifications': [{
            'attachFile': False,
            'attachStdError': False,
            'attachStdOut': False,
            'bcc': None,
            'body': None,
}
```

the code i am using

```
with open("/sbranch/CTK/SAP/hkeep/vrpoutput.json", 'w') as file:
    json_string = json.dumps(mydict, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=True)
    file.write(json_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally i have created dictionary from the output received from api call. It was easier for me to make the changes in dictionary.But i have changed my logic a bit instead of dictionary, i have written the output from api to a file and used regular expression to change the strings what i need.

```
orig_string=""""type": "taskSap",
"actions": {
    "abortActions": [],
    "emailNotifications": [],
    "setVariableActions": [345erd],
    "snmpNotifications": [],
    "systemOperations": []
}"""

newstring='"All is good"'
ss = re.search(r"\"setVariableActions.*?,", orig_string)
if ss:
    pattern=(ss.group(0))
    #print(pattern)
result=orig_string.replace(pattern,newstring)
print(result)
```